# Codeigniter - Ajax Request works, how to handle standart request?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I work with Codeigniter and I want to tackle following problem.

I tried to ajaxify my project and this works perfectly.

The ajax onclick event works.

But when I visit the url through my browser (e. g. visit my homepage via external website)

of course no content will be displayed, because it is not an ajax request.

I tried a couple of things but I can not manage it.

**File: application/core/My_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $templatedata = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    //collect all css, js stuff
        //$this->templatedata['css'] = all css stuff and so on
    } 

    
    
    public function __destruct()
    {
    parent::__destruct();
    echo $this->load->view('deskapp2/html/index',$this->templatedata,true);
    }
}
```

So first I collect my css and js files.

In the destructor I echo-out my main-template.

**File: application/view/deskapp2/html/index**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- loop css files -->
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- part of the menu -->
    <li><a class="loveit" rel="index" href="<?php echo $base;?>welcome">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="loveit" rel="mytest" href="<?php echo $base;?>welcome/mytest">Test 2</a></li>

    <!-- this is for the ajax-request -->
    <div id="showmystuff"></div>

    <!-- this is for the non-ajax-request -->
    <?php echo $content;?>

  <!-- other js files -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.loveit').click(function (e) {
    
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var targetUri = $(this).attr('rel');
    
    var arrUrl = targetUri.split('/');
    
    //alert(arrUrl);
    //url:"http://localhost/3113/public/ajax/index"
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState("","",targetUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/3113/public/ajax/index",
        type: "POST",
        data:{arr:targetUri},
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            //alert('test');
            $('#showmystuff').html('<b>'+data+'</b>');
            
        },
        error:function (){
            alert('Something went wrong');
        },
    });
    
}); 
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**File: controller/Ajax.php**

This controller is for ajax calls.

```
class Ajax extends CommonController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            echo 'You are here: '.$this->input->post('arr'); //shows the full uri-string of the link which is clicked, see javascript in index.html
        }
    }
    
    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }
}
```

My plan here is of course to load all the stuff from a database depending on the uri.

**File: controller/welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends FrontendController {

    
    
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //some stuff
    }

    public function mytest()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            echo $this->load->view('welcome_message', NULL, true);
        }
        else
        {   
            $this->templatedata['content'] = 'some stuff';
        }
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $this->templatedata['content'] = 'load from db...';
        }
    }
    
        
    
    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }
}
```

I know that the Ajax-Controller is not really nessecary. :D

I just play around.

**Summary:**

How can I differentiate between an ajax-request and a non-ajax-request?

Any hints? :)

Thanks to everyone who reads this.

And like I said. I am not professional and I just play around to improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to reliably differentiate between an Ajax call, a browser link request, or a page form request since they all support HTTP methods such as POST, GET, DELETE, and Put. The only exception is that browser link requests can only use the GET method.

One solution to distinguish them is to include a unique header in the Ajax request on the client-side
Example with pure ajax:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'your-url');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Is-Ajax-Request'', 'True');
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // handle successful response here
  } else {
    // handle error response here
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  // handle error response here
};
xhr.send(data); // your data here
```

Example with jQuery.ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your-url',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-Is-Ajax-Request': 'True'
  },
  data: {
    // your data here
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // handle successful response here
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // handle error response here
  }
});
```

You can check for the existence of this header in your PHP code to identify if the request was sent via Ajax or not.

Example PHP code:

```
function is_ajax_request() {
  return $_SERVER['X-Is-Ajax-Request'] == "True";
}
```